# How to convert a structure of type "buffer" to a json array in NodeJs and Express

Tags: node.js, json, express

When I call my api with the https npm module, it returns this structure:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[55,74,49,66,73,102,85,]}
```

What I want instead a JSON file.
How do I convert it?

Comment: Show your API.. I'd assume you need to convert the buffer to a JSON string before returning.

Comment: const request = await https.request(options, (res) => {

            res.on('data',async (d) => {
                if(typeof d === 'string' || d instanceof String){
                    console.log("\n\n\nEra una stinga "+ d + "\n\n\n");
                    clienti = JSON.parse(d);
                }else{
                    const objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(d);
                    const objJsonB64 = new Buffer(objJsonStr).toString("base64");
                    console.log("\n\n\nEra un'oggeto "+ JSON.stringify(objJsonB64) + "\n\n\n");
                    clienti = d;
               }

Comment: it's just a little pice because has too many char

Comment: How can i convert the buffer to JSON? i'm doign this:
 const objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(d);
                    const objJsonB64 = new Buffer(objJsonStr).toString("base64");
                    console.log("\n\n\nEra un'oggeto "+ JSON.stringify(objJsonB64) + "\n\n\n"); Where d is the data recived from the api

Comment: Okay, in that case, just do `const response = JSON.parse(objJsonB64.toString())` and return your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this buffer usually means that the data have not finished to arrive, so I've solved my problem like this:

```js
var data = "";
//Function to recieve the JSON even it's too long
res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});

//As I stop reciving data I send back the response
res.on("end", function () {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    resp.send({
        message: "Ok",
        status: 200,
        data: data,
    });
});
```